# Prime factorization problem...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here's the entire problem:

> By considering the prime decomposition of $gcd( ab, n )$, show that if $a , b ,n$ are integers with $n$ relatively prime to both $a,b$ , then $n$ is relatively prime to $ab$.

Okay so I know how to do this via non-prime factorization. Here's my attempt at a start to this problem:

> **Proof**
>
> Given $a,b$ relatively prime to $n$, $\exists$ $s,t,u \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t
> $$as+nu=1$$
> $$bt+nu=1$$
> If we consider the prime factorization of $a,b,n$, we have primes $p_i,q_i,v_i$ s.t
> $$a=\prod_{i=1}^r (p_i)^{n_i}$$
> $$b=\prod_{i=1}^r (q_i)^{j_i}$$
> $$n=\prod_{i=1}^r (v_i)^{\gamma_i}.$$
> Note that $ab=(p_1)^{n_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot(p_r)^{n_r}(q_1)^{j_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot(q_r)^{j_r}$. Our result to ultimately prove is that $$abs+nu=1$$

Where do I go from here? I know how to progress without prime factorization, but that's not how the proof is supposed to be done :| If anyone could help, I'd be much obliged!

Comment: If ab and n have a common factor, it has a prime dividing it, but then this prime divides both ab and n, a contradiction.

Comment: If the intention is to solve this problem using prime factorization, then the equations that equal $1$ aren't going to be relevant to this solution. Do you know what it means, in terms of prime factorizations, for two integers to be relatively prime?

Comment: Doesn't is just mean that they share no common prime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Greg Martin said, if you will use prime factorization arguments, there's no need to invoke Bézout's Lemma.

The definition of $\gcd$ in terms of prime factorization is usually as follows. If the prime factorization of $a,b$ is given by
$$a=p_{1}^{\,\alpha_1}p_{2}^{\,\alpha_2}\,...$$
$$b=p_{1}^{\,\beta_1}p_{b_2}^{\,\beta_2}\,...$$

where $(p_1,p_2,...)$ = $(2,3,5,...)$, that is, the prime numbers, then:
$$\gcd(a,b)=p_1^{\,\min(\alpha_1,\beta_1)}p_2^{\,\min(\alpha_2,\beta_2)}\,...$$

With this, we can prove your statement. Using the above definitions:
$$ab=p_{1}^{\,\alpha_1+\beta_1}p_{2}^{\,\alpha_2+\beta_2}\,...$$

And let $n = p_1^{\,\nu_1}p_2^{\,\nu_2}\,...$ be the prime factorization of $n$. Since $n$ is relatively prime with $a$ and $b$, if $\alpha_k>0$ then $\nu_k=0$, and likewise, if $\beta_k > 0$, then $\nu_k = 0$. So, we have two cases to consider:

- $\alpha_k+\beta_k=0$. In this case, since $\nu_k$ is a nonnegative integer, 
  $\min(\alpha_k+\beta_k,\nu_k)=\min(0,\nu_k)=0$.
- $\alpha_k+\beta_k>0$. Then at least one of $\alpha_k$, $\beta_k$ is greater than zero. Either way, $\nu_k=0$ so $\min(\alpha_k+\beta_k,\nu_k)=\min(\alpha_k+\beta_k,0)=0$.

With this, we've proved that $\min(\alpha_k+\beta_k,\nu_k)=0$ for any $k\in \Bbb{N}$, so that:
$$\gcd(ab,n)=p_1^{\,\min(\alpha_1+\beta_1,\nu_1)}p_2^{\,\min(\alpha_2+\beta_2,\nu_2)}\,...=p_1^{\,0}p_2^{\,0}\,...=1\cdot1\,\cdot\,\,...=1$$

And so, $ab$ and $n$ are relatively prime by definition.

Comment: This looks great! I was just curious about the lower part of the proof where we have our two cases. Why does the case of $\alpha_k + \beta_k = 0$ $\implies$ $v_k > 0$? We know that $a,b$ are relatively prime to $n$, yes, but I don't know that entails that $\alpha_k + \beta_k = 0$ $\implies$ $v_k > 0$

Comment: It is nonnegative, i.e. $\nu_k \geq 0$. In fact, it is always nonnegative whether $\alpha_k + \beta_k = 0$ or not, but when  $\alpha_k + \beta_k = 0$ it doesn't matter what's the value of $\nu_k$ since the $\min$ will be $0$. But you're right, $\nu_k$ can be $0$ and that wouldn't change the result!

Comment: I guess let me extend the question to the second case. Why does $\alpha_k + \beta_k > 0$ $\implies v_k=0$? I think that was what really threw me off. If $\alpha_k =$ some value and $\beta_k=0$ (or $\beta_k=$ some value and $\alpha_k=0$), then I totally get it. But what how does the sum of $\alpha_k,\beta_k$ tell us, based on our construction, that $v_k=0$?

Comment: Since $\alpha_k$ and $\beta_k$ are nonnegative integers, if their sum is greater than $0$ then at least one of them is greater than $0$. This implies that $\nu_k=0$, for if say $\alpha_k > 0$ and $\nu_k > 0$, then $p_k$ divides both $a$ and $n$ (so they're not relatively prime). Same thing goes for $\beta_k$.

Comment: I think it all makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!